# Is this a valid GRIB geotransform? (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0)

Tags: python, gdal

I am attempting to warp RAP grib file from the noaa server:
https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/rap/prod/rap.20220928/rap.t06z.wrfprsf03.grib2

But I see that this file has a geotransform of `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0)`

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.SetConfigOption('VSI_CACHE', 'TRUE')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN', 'TRUE')
gdal.UseExceptions()
filename=f"/vsicurl/https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/rap/prod/rap.20220928/rap.t06z.wrfprsf03.grib2"

gribdata = gdal.Open(filename)

print(gribdata.GetGeoTransform())

>>> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0)
```

I have processed other files from this FTP server (HRRR, NAM, etc) and they all have correct Geotransforms.

This file is not working with gdal Warp
It gives an error `

```
    return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 3987, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
RuntimeError: Cannot invert geotransform
```

I assume this is because the GeoTransform is all-zeros.

I would like to report this as an issue to NOAA, but before I do this I'd like to be 100% sure that this GeoTransform is in fact incorrect. It seems so because [1] and [5] in the vector should be the resolution, and they are also zero. Is this correct?
Or am I missing something here?

(Also, does anyone know where to report this issue to the NOAA? it seems I can't use this file like this)

Here's an example file that works:
https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20220928/conus/hrrr.t07z.wrfprsf07.grib2

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.SetConfigOption('VSI_CACHE', 'TRUE')
gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN', 'TRUE')
gdal.UseExceptions()
filename=f"/vsicurl/https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20220928/conus/hrrr.t07z.wrfprsf07.grib2"

gribdata = gdal.Open(filename)

print(gribdata.GetGeoTransform())

>>> (-2699020.1425219304, 3000.0, 0.0, 1588193.8474433364, 0.0, -3000.0)


    [17:18 stacey ~/Downloads]
    $ gdalinfo 20220928_hrrr.t07z.wrfprsf07.grib2
    Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
    Files: 20220928_hrrr.t07z.wrfprsf07.grib2
    Size is 1799, 1059
    Coordinate System is:
    PROJCRS["unnamed",
        BASEGEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
            DATUM["unnamed",
                ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6371229,0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
        CONVERSION["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
                ID["EPSG",9802]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",38.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8821]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",262.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8822]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",38.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8823]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",38.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8824]],
            PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,                                                                                                                                                                    
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],                                                                                                                                                                                
                ID["EPSG",8826]],                                                                                                                                                                                     
            PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,                                                                                                                                                                   
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],                                                                                                                                                                                
                ID["EPSG",8827]]],                                                                                                                                                                                    
        CS[Cartesian,2],                                                                                                                                                                                              
            AXIS["(E)",east,                                                                                                                                                                                          
                ORDER[1],                                                                                                                                                                                             
                LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1]],                                                                                                                                                                               
            AXIS["(N)",north,                                                                                                                                                                                         
                ORDER[2],                                                                                                                                                                                             
                LENGTHUNIT["Metre",1]]]                                                                                                                                                                               
    Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2                                                                                                                                                                                
    Origin = (-2699020.142521930392832,1588193.847443336388096)
    Pixel Size = (3000.000000000000000,-3000.000000000000000)
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (-2699020.143, 1588193.847) (134d 7'17.14"W, 47d50'44.64"N)
    Lower Left  (-2699020.143,-1588806.153) (122d43'44.80"W, 21d 7'19.89"N)
    Upper Right ( 2697979.857, 1588193.847) ( 60d53'28.48"W, 47d50'57.51"N)
    Lower Right ( 2697979.857,-1588806.153) ( 72d16'48.48"W, 21d 7'28.62"N)
    Center      (    -520.143,    -306.153) ( 97d30'21.52"W, 38d29'50.09"N)
```